# Yahoo Pipes - Remove all word or tag before match

Tags: regex, url, match, matching, yahoo-pipes

for example, I have some feed, with an item title like this

**Some text is better than one text http://t.co/blablabla #hashtag**

then I want to get only the URL using regex like this

http://t.co/blablabla

how do i do that ?

(sorry I use google translate to make this question)

thanks for answer

Comment: Could you format your question using the tools available in the editor? I can't really get what you want to match.

Comment: @sp00m and Pshemo thanks for guide me? this my first question on http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: So you're looking for a regexp matching URLs in strings? Have you searched on Internet before? It's quite a common job...

Comment: yes bro I search on google but I dont have good result on search no one solve my problem, if u have solution please share with us, thanks

Comment: Could you share what you already tried? What language are you using?

Comment: I dont know what programing language I using on Yahoo Pipes

Answer (score 0):

Here's a random one I found with a simple google search:

(http|ftp|https)://([\w-_]+(?:(?:.[\w-_]+)+))([\w-.,@?^=%&:/~+#]*[\w-\@?^=%&/~+#])?

Comment: the result of your regex is remove the link bro..I want just put link and remove all word

Comment: just use a match function instead of a remove function then.